# matplotlib crashes on Manjaro Linux

Tags: manjaro, segmentation-fault

I have the latest version of Manjaro Gnome installed, kernel 5.9.8, and python 3.8.6 and matplotlib 3.3.3. Matplotlib works fine normally, for example, when images are displayed using pylab, I can interact with the popup to edit the margins and so on (see attached image).

However, I click on the save button, nothing happens in xorg session. On the terminal, the following message is printed

```
"/proc/14640/root"
```

On a Wayland session, the messages from terminal are

```
"Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.

"/proc/16207/root"
```

and when I click on the save button, the app crashes with the following segmentation fault error

```
"zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped) python test.py"
```

test.py is the sample plotting script used to test matplotlib. I do not encounter this problem with matplotlib on macos or Ubuntu. If anyone can help with this error I would really appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: What is your backend (`import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.get_backend())`)? Can you switch to a different interactive backend? Side note: don't use pylab. Use numpy and pyplot separately.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your answer solved my problem. I was using Qt5Agg, and switching to GTK5Agg did the trick. 

As a side, using GTK5Agg on Wayland cannot load the cursor theme, and I had to resort to xorg. But that is fine.

Comment: That's good to hear, because I wouldn't have had any other idea, and I don't know what could have gone wrong with your Qt :) Feel free to self-answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Andras Deak](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/416002/andras-deak)'s suggestion I was able to solve this problem. The error arises from the defeault Qt5Agg backend I was using, and switching to GTK3Agg backend solved the problem (and gives much better theming in the Gnome session).

Not sure what is wrong with the Qt on my system. One downside of using GTK3Agg on Wayland is that cursor theme could not be loaded. There is a workaround here

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cursor_themes

I just switched to xorg for simplicity.